# Underline navbar when active

Tags: css, wordpress

In my navbar on the following page: [My Example][1] , I would like each menu has an underline, when the menu is active.

I tried to set the following in the CSS, but I still do not get any underline when I click on a menu option. Am I setting the `text-decoration: underline !important;` on the wrong class?

```
.genesis-nav-menu a:active {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 1.6rem 0;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, using Chrome

Comment: you used the :active selector in your example, so the a tag will only be underlined in the moment you click on it. You can read more about the :active selector here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have an `.active` class ?

I don't see any `.active` in the web console.

I see in the source code that it is : `.current-menu-item`

So you can do  :

```
.current-menu-item {
     text-decoration: underline;
     /* add other style if you want. */
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you a lot. That is working for me. I can first accept your answer in 9 minutes. Should it also be here that I can set a color in the text? fx color: red; or is that on another class again?

Comment: with ".current-menu-item a" you will be able to set the color as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.current-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of using WordPress, you can target it's native `.current-menu-item` class and style it to your liking.